# Laurent series(finding)

Tags: complex-analysis

I dont know how to make the Laurent series expansion of this functions
$$\frac{1}{(z+1)(z-3)(z+4)}  ,3<|z+1|<4;$$

$$\frac{(z+2)^2}{(z-i)^2} ,   2<|z+i|<\infty$$

Comment: What are your first steps to solve and what is the difficulty for you? Then we are able to give you a hint or just one step towards the solution

Comment: I'm assuming you know how to expand stuff like $1/(z+1)$. Can you think of a partial fraction decomposition of the above?

Comment: the problem is that i havent even idea how to solve this

Comment: Here is a [relates problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/228529/find-laurent-expansion-of-fracz-1z-2z-3-in-annulus-z2z3/228635#228635).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For these types of questions it is important to know the Laurent expansion of $(z-a)^{-1}$ for both $|z|\leq a$ and $|z| \geq a$. I hope you can easily convince yourself that
$$\tag{1} \frac{1}{z-a} = -\frac{1}{a} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{z}{a}\right)^n, \qquad |z| \leq a $$
and
$$\tag{2} \frac{1}{z-a} =  \frac{1}{z} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{a}{z}\right)^n, \qquad |z| \geq a.$$

I will show you how it works for the first question
$$\frac{1}{(z+1)(z-3)(z+4)}  ,3<|z+1|<4;$$ and I believe you can the do it yourself for the second. The Laurent series should be expanded in a ring centered at $z_0=-1$. Thus, we introduce $w=z+1$. We then have the problem
$$\frac{1}{w(w-4)(w+3)}  ,3<|w|<4;$$

Next we perform a partial fraction expansion and obtain
$$\frac{1}{w(w-4)(w+3)}= -\frac{1}{12 w}+\frac{1}{21 (w+3)}+\frac{1}{28 (w-4)} .$$
For each of the terms you should now think whether you have to apply (1) or (2).

Comment: @molniya: does this help?