# Rigorous proof of Basel problem

Tags: complex-analysis

I've read Euler's proof for Basel  problem and I was wondering what were the details it was missing.

Based on that proof, this is my try, do you think it is correct or is any detail missing?

Thanks a lot for the replays.

**Proof:**

By Wierstrass factorization theorem we know that

$$\dfrac{\sin z}{z}={\displaystyle \prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left( 1-\dfrac{z^2}{n^2\pi^2}\right)}$$

Then, if we define

$$P_k(z)={\displaystyle \prod_{n=1}^{k}\left( 1-\dfrac{z^2}{n^2\pi^2}\right)}$$

we can observe that

$P_1(z)=1-\dfrac{z^2}{\pi^2}$

$P_2(z)=1-\dfrac{1}{\pi^2}\left( 1+\dfrac{1}{4}\right)z^2+\dfrac{1}{4\pi^4}z^4=1-\dfrac{1}{\pi^2}\left( 1+\dfrac{1}{4}\right)z^2+o(z^3)$

So, lets proof by induction that

$$P_k(z)=1-\dfrac{1}{\pi^2}\left( {\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{k} \dfrac{1}{i^2}}\right)z^2+o(z^3)$$

The base case is already proven so lets assume it is true for $k$, then we have that

$P_{k+1}(z)={\displaystyle \prod_{n=1}^{k+1}\left( 1-\dfrac{z^2}{n^2\pi^2}\right)}={\displaystyle \prod_{n=1}^{k}\left( 1-\dfrac{z^2}{n^2\pi^2}\right)} \left(1- \dfrac{z^2}{(k+1)^2\pi^2}\right)=P_k(z) \left(1- \dfrac{z^2}{(k+1)^2\pi^2}\right)= \left( 1-\dfrac{1}{\pi^2}\left( {\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{k} \dfrac{1}{i^2}}\right)z^2+o(z^3) \right) \left(1- \dfrac{z^2}{(k+1)^2\pi^2}\right)\\=1-\dfrac{1}{\pi^2}\left( {\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{k+1} \dfrac{1}{i^2}}\right)z^2+\dfrac{1}{(k+1)^2\pi^4}\left( {\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{k} \dfrac{1}{i^2}}\right)z^4+\left(1- \dfrac{z^2}{(k+1)^2\pi^2}\right) o(z^3)\\=1-\dfrac{1}{\pi^2}\left( {\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{k+1} \dfrac{1}{i^2}}\right)z^2+o(z^3)$

because

${\displaystyle \lim_{z \to 0} \dfrac{1}{z^3} \left( \dfrac{1}{(k+1)^2\pi^4}\left( {\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{k} \dfrac{1}{i^2}}\right)z^4+\left(1- \dfrac{z^2}{(k+1)^2\pi^2}\right) o(z^3) \right)}= {\displaystyle \lim_{z \to 0} \dfrac{1}{(k+1)^2\pi^4}\left( {\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{k} \dfrac{1}{i^2}}\right)z^3}+{\displaystyle \lim_{z \to 0}\left(1- \dfrac{z^2}{(k+1)^2\pi^2}\right) \dfrac{o(z^3)}{z^3}}=0$

Then, we have that

$$\dfrac{\sin(z)}{z}={\displaystyle \lim_{k \to \infty} P_k}={\displaystyle \lim_{k \to \infty} \left(1-\dfrac{1}{\pi^2}\left( {\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{k} \dfrac{1}{i^2}}\right)z^2+o(z^3) \right)}=1-\dfrac{1}{\pi^2}\left( {\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{n^2}}\right)z^2+o(z^3) \hspace{1mm} (1)$$

On the other hand, by the MacLaurin series expansion of $\sin(z)$ and by the fact that the product of two Laurent series is another Laurent series with coefficients as specify here ([Multiplying Laurent series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359921/multiplying-laurent-series)), we get that the Taylor series for our function is

$$\dfrac{\sin(z)}{z}={\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \dfrac{1}{(2k+1)!} z^{2k}}$$

Then, we can express

$$\dfrac{\sin(z)}{z}=1-\dfrac{1}{6} z^2 +o(z^3)$$

and because of (1) and the uniqness of Taylor's polynomials, we conclude that for every $z \in \mathbb{C}$

$$1-\dfrac{1}{\pi^2}\left( {\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{n^2}}\right)z^2 = 1-\dfrac{1}{6} z^2$$

from were we conclude that

$${\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{n^2}}= \dfrac{\pi^2}{6}$$

**Note:**

In (1), I'm not sure if it is correct that

$${\displaystyle \lim_{k \to \infty} o(z^3)}=o(z^3)$$

My reasoning is that given $\varepsilon >0$, we know that there exists some $\delta >0$ such that if $0<|z|<\delta$

$$\left | \dfrac{o(z^3)}{z^3} \right| < \varepsilon, \hspace{1mm}$$

So, if $0<|z|<\delta$ we have that

$$\left | \dfrac{1}{z^3} {\displaystyle \lim_{k \to \infty} o(z^3)}\right|=\left | {\displaystyle \lim_{k \to \infty} \dfrac{o(z^3)}{z^3}}\right| = {\displaystyle \lim_{k \to \infty} \left | \dfrac{o(z^3)}{z^3}\right| } <\varepsilon$$

and then, ${\displaystyle \lim_{k \to \infty} o(z^3)}=o(z^3)$.

Comment: I think the bulk of the real work here is done by the Weierstraß factorization theorem (which was not available to Euler).

Comment: Actually knowing anything about the coefficient on any $z^n$ ($n \ge 3$) term is irrelevant so long as we know it converges; we already know the infinite product does, so we are essentially done.

Comment: The discussion about the term $o(z^3)$ indeed needs more rigor. Because as you multiply more and more terms, the hidden constant might go increasing and even diverge.

Comment: @YvesDaoust It is true, and I'm not able to proof that the limit of the remainders I get from every $Pk(z)$ is in fact an $o(z^3)$ without assuming that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$. Any ideas of how to do it?

Comment: @Eparoh you could do a bit of rearranging in the infinite product to show it converges as I allude to above (you already know the infinite product converges, since $\sin(z)$ is finite for all $z$, which quickly gives you that all coefficients must be finite with a little thought) or you could some inequality estimates, either on the product itself, by weakening the terms to a known product/series, etc. Try a couple things and respond with how your attempts have gone.