# What is the Laurent series of $e^{z+z^{-1}}$? (Detailed derivation using Cauchy product of series)

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series, cauchy-product

We know that:
$$e^{z+z^{-1}}=\underbrace{\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n!}\right)\cdot\left(\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^{-m}}{m!}\right)}_{=:\alpha}.$$
Now I am having trouble, applying the following ([Cauchy product for series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product)) on $\alpha$:
$$\left(\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_iz^i\right)\cdot\left(\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}b_jz^j\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}c_k z^k, \quad c_k=\sum_{l=0}^{k}a_lb_{k-l}. \quad (\ast)$$
My approach was the following:
With ($\ast$) I find that
\begin{align}
\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n!}\right)\cdot\left(\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^{-m}}{m!}\right) &= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}c_k, \\
c_k &= \sum_{l=0}^{k}\left(\frac{1}{l!}\frac{1}{(-(k-l))!}\right) \\
&= \sum_{l=0}^{k}\frac{1}{l!(l-k)!},
\end{align}
which results in
$$e^{z+z^{-1}}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{l=0}^{k}\frac{1}{l!(l-k)!}\right)z^k.$$
The result I am looking for is
$$e^{z+z^{-1}}=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{l!(l+k)!}\right)z^k, \quad \forall k\in\mathbb{N}_0.$$
What am I missing?
Also, I suspect that I have to use the following
$$\alpha=\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n!}\right)\cdot\left(\sum_{m=-\infty}^{0}\frac{z^m}{(-m)!}\right)$$
in order to get a sum from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, but I do not know how.

Comment: What have you tried, and where are you getting stuck?

Comment: As a simple for-instance: can you figure out what the coefficient of $z^0$ should be?

Comment: Your forgot the $b_j$ on the left side of your Cauchy sum. But since one of your series is a power series in $z^{-1},$ the equivalent Cauchy sums are infinite. For example, the coefficient of $z^0$ in $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!\cdot n!}.$$ I doubt that has a closed form.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I updated the question.

Comment: The result you're 'expecting' to get is clearly wrong; as Thomas Andrews points out, the coefficient of $z^0$ is definitely not 1. You can see that your own result is incorrect because since $e^{z+z^{-1}}$ is symmetric with respect to $z$ and $z^{-1}$, so the Laurent series coefficients must likewise be symmetric; for every positive coefficient $a_kz^k$ there's an equal negative coefficient $a_kz^{-k}$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I believe it's representable as $I_0(2)$ with $I_0$ a modified Bessel function, though of course whether that's a closed form is a matter of opinion.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki You are right! I edited the question (the upper limit of the sum should not have been $k$, but $\infty$ instead). What am I missing now?

Comment: The problem is that you are forcing the Cauchy product on a problem where it is not applicable. The Cauchy product is for two power series in the *same* variable. Here you have one power series in $z$ and another in $1/z$. There is a (formal) extension to Laurent series that you can use though: $$
\left( {\sum\limits_{n =  - \infty }^\infty  {a_n z^n } } \right)\left( {\sum\limits_{n =  - \infty }^\infty  {b_n z^n } } \right) = \sum\limits_{n =  - \infty }^\infty  {\left( {\sum\limits_{k =  - \infty }^\infty  {a_k b_{n - k} } } \right)z^n } .
$$

Comment: @Gary How do I have to transform the sums in order to make them suitable for the Cauchy product? (How do I get to the form you present in your comment?)

Comment: See the rigorous derivation in the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359921/multiplying-laurent-series). It shows how to multiply two Laurent series in the intersection of their annuli of convergence.