# Find the 3 laurent series of $f(z)=\frac{3}{(1-z)(z+2)}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, partial-fractions, laurent-series

Find the Laurent series of
$$f(z)=\frac{3}{(1-z)(z+2)}$$ centered at $0$ with the three domains $|z|<1$, $1<|z|<2$, $2<|z|$. I know you use partial fractions and I got $\frac{1}{1-z} + \frac{1}{z+2}+\dots$. If I could get help with one of them on how to find one of them that would be awesome.

Comment: your second domain must be $\,1<|z|<2\,$ , not what you wrote.

Comment: A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/228529/find-laurent-expansion-of-fracz-1z-2z-3-in-annulus-z2z3/228635#228635).

Answer (score 2):

For example:

$$1<|z|<2\implies \frac{1}{1-z}+\frac{1}{2+z}=-\frac{1}{z}\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{z}}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{1+\frac{z}{2}}=$$

$$=-\frac{1}{z}\left(1+\frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{z^2}+\ldots\right)+\frac{1}{2}\left(1-\frac{z}{2}+\frac{z^2}{2^4}-\frac{z^3}{2^3}+\ldots\right)$$

Complete the above, explain the steps and then do something similar for the other domains.

Comment: can you explain why you chose to split it up how you did?

Comment: Because $$|z|>1\iff \frac{1}{|z|}<1\implies \frac{1}{1\pm\frac{1}{z}}\;\;\text{has a convergent series}$$ By the same token, $$|z|<2\iff \frac{|z|}{2}<1\implies\frac{1}{1+\frac{z}{2}}\;\;\text{has a convergent series}\ldots$$

Comment: that makes sense. thank you for the help!