# Obtain the Laurent expansions of $1/(z+i)$ valid for |z|>1

Tags: complex-analysis

**Background** Wunsch-Complex Variables 3e 5.6#6

My attempt:
$\sum_{0}^\infty\frac{1}{z}\left (\frac{-i}{z}\right )^n=(\frac{1}{z}-\frac{i}{z^2}-\frac{1}{z^3}+\frac{i}{z^4}\dots)$

Author's solution:
$\sum_{-\infty}^{-1}(\color{red}{-1})\left ((-i)^{1-n}z^n\right )=(\frac{1}{z}-\frac{i}{z^2}+\frac{i^2}{z^3}+\frac{\color{red}{i^3}}{z^4}\dots)$

Did I make a mistake? Where did red -1 come from?

I can show my steps but it's just a straight forward application of the formula you can find [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1869670/laurent-expansions-of-frac1z-1) as described by Markus Scheuer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula is fine, so is the authors. They just use a different enumeration. The two ways are related by $n\mapsto -1-n$. Starting with $1-(-1)=2$ they add the factor $(-1)=i^2$ in front. There is indeed a sign misprint regarding  their coefficient to $z^{-4}$. I think yours is more clear.

Comment: Yes, his formula is right, it was a typo on $c_4$. Funny that the first time I read it I mentally calculated the same value as the typo.

Answer (score 0):

First put $$\omega=\frac{1}{z}$$
Function becomes
$$\frac{\omega}{\omega+i}\\$$
Now expanding$ \frac{1}{\omega+i} $by binomial theorem we get
$$\frac{1}{\omega+i}=1-i\omega+({i\omega})^2-......\\$$
now put this result in modified function and replace $\omega=\frac{1}{z}$